# How to Block Http Methods in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3, http-headers, http-verbs

We have a requirement of disabling the HTTP methods besides POST, GET and Head in an ASPNET Core Web application due as a part of security fixes. How can we disable the HTTP OPTIONS method in ASP.Net core  API?
Allowed 3 methods which are POST,GET and Head.
How to block all the others method which I didn't use in middleware like DELETE,TRACE,PATCH and etc.
Needs to return Error Code 405 = Method Not Allowed . Currently it throws the error 500 which is Internal Server Error

my code right now .

```
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Method=="TRACE")
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 405;
                    return; 
                }
                await next.Invoke();
            });
```

How to Block Http Methods in ASP.NET

Comment: Seems like you want an allow list instead of a deny list. Only accept requests that are POST, GET and HEAD. What you have looks fine.

Answer (score 2):

You could try as below:

```
app.MapWhen(x => x.Request.Method == "somemethod",
                y => y.Use(async(context,next)=>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 405;
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Method Not Allowed");
                }
            ));
```

The Result:

[image]